# Smarty one tag inside another

Tags: smarty

I want to assign some value with included smarty value to another, like this:

```
{assign var="one" value="hello world {$two}"}
```

but error is happened. Please help how resolve it.

Answer (score 3):

you should not use limiters in limiters i guess.

```
{assign var="one" value="hello world $two"}
```

worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Resolved

```
{assign var="one" value="hello world $two"}
```

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution to this particular case is to use the `|cat` modifier, since modifiers can be used wherever you would normally have a string or variable.

```
 {assign var=one value="hello "|cat:$two}
```